# sqlite count rows of tables identified by subquery

Tags: sqlite

I want to get the count of rows in every table in a Sqlite3 database. I want to avoid writing out a longhand query. I can get the list of tables like this:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

and I would like to use it in a subquery like this:

```
select count (*) from (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table');
```

but would just return the total rows in the subquery, which isn't what I want.

How can I write a query that will list each table along with their counts?

I have seen *dynamic SQL* for this kind of thing but I don't think SQLite has that.

I have written a *bash* loop to do this but I would prefer to do it as a single query

```
for t in $(sqlite3 data.db "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"); do
  echo -n "$t = "; sqlite3 data.db "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $t;"
done
```

Ideas appreciated

Comment: What do you need that count for?

Comment: To see how many records of each type were there. Ultimately to delete entries from `sqlite_sequence` for empty tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know these values for debugging purposes, look at the output of the [sqlite3_analyzer](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) tool.

If you want to use these values in your program, you have to generate the queries dynamically in your program.

Comment: By *generate the queries dynamically in your program* do you mean in my SQL or in the *program* that calls the SQL, like the bash snippet in my question? I presume you mean the latter, in which case I infer that you mean that *dymanic SQL* is not possible in SQLite. Would that inference be correct?

Comment: Yes; SQLite is designed to be embedded in a 'real' program.

Answer (score 7):

I used the following shell syntax to blindly get counts from tables in a database I was debugging.

```
db="database.db"

for i in `sqlite3 "$db" "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"`;
    do echo -n $i\ \=\ ;
    sqlite3 "$db" "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $i";
done


cols = 0
sqlite_sequence = 0
datacols = 17
hits = 0
host = 0
document = 0
admin = 2
comments = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code will use full for some one.

I've written the sample code in C#.net Programming language and Nuget Package is  Microsoft.Data.Sqlite with version of 7.0.10

Code :

```
internal class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {        
    string dbMainQuery = $" WITH x(i) AS (select name from \"main\".sqlite_master WHERE type='table') \r\n SELECT PRINTF('SELECT count(*) as NumberOfRow FROM %s;',i) as QueryInfo,i as Tablename FROM x ;";
    DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtTableCountInfo = new DataTable();
    dtTableCountInfo.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
    dtTableCountInfo.Columns.Add("TableName", typeof(string));
    dtTableCountInfo.Columns.Add("TotalCount", typeof(string));
    //Get the sqlite all db data
    using (SqliteConnection sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=dataStoreage.db;Pooling=True;"))
    {
        sqliteConnection.Open();
        using var transaction = sqliteConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        try
        {
            using SqliteCommand sqliteCommand = new SqliteCommand(dbMainQuery, sqliteConnection, transaction);
            var dataReader = sqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
            dtMain.Load(dataReader);

            // Itration on the each table and get the row numbers
            if (dtMain.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtMain.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var rowInfo = dtTableCountInfo.NewRow();
                    using SqliteCommand countInfoCmd = new SqliteCommand(dtMain.Rows[i][0].ToString(), sqliteConnection, transaction);
                    rowInfo["Id"] = i + 1;
                    rowInfo["TableName"] = dtMain.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    rowInfo["TotalCount"] = countInfoCmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    dtTableCountInfo.Rows.Add(rowInfo);
                }
            }
            transaction.Commit();
            // TO DO : do the conversion of the data table as per your needs
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            transaction.RollbackAsync();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

and the Model class :

```
public class TableSummryReport
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```